# ejs : Add dynamic parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, parameters, ejs

I would like to create a general function in javascript, using the module EJS.
I have this line

```
res.render(PageName,{test:"abc"});
```

But I should hard write the parameter id "test". I would like to avoid that.
I tried to put everything in a string ("{test:abc}"), but it doesn't work.
How could I manage to have this line :

```
res.render(PageName,data);
```

with data containing one or several parameters id:"value" ?
Thanks

Comment: I think that, your question is more related to javascript itself than, with any other question. you can generate a dynamic json, object, array... whatever you like and pass it. What is your question, is it how to create an object dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to create dynamic data to pass,
try this (one possible solution):

```
var data = {};

data['key1'] = 'a';
data['key2'] = 'b';
data['key3'] = 12321;
data['key4'] = [1, 2, 3];
data['key5'] = {foo: 'bar'};

res.render(PageName,data);
```